# Blender Python Console Commands not completing before next one is interpreted?

Tags: python, command-line

I'm working with the default Blender file that has single cube object.
I'm rotating it with Python and adding keyframes.
The problem is that a `bpy.ops.transform.rotate()` seems to take some time to execute so when I paste in a series of commands a keyframe is created before the rotation actually happens.
If I paste commands in one at a time I get my expected animations. Is there a "finished" event, or "wait for last" command I can use?

This code pasted in the Console may show rotations on some of the keyframes and not on others, it is inconsistent.

```
bpy.context.scene.frame_current = 0
bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert()

bpy.context.scene.frame_current = 30

bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=1.5708, axis=(1, 0, 0), constraint_axis=(True, False, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, release_confirm=False)

bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert()

bpy.context.scene.frame_current = 60

bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=-1.5708, axis=(0, 1, 0), constraint_axis=(False, True, False), constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, release_confirm=False)

bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert()

... and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

**Ditch the operators and use the API**

Example script, rotates object 90 degrees about z axis. Inserts all keyframes of active keying set at frame 30.  Not using any operators or changing the frame, simply set a property and call keyframe_insert.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Matrix
from math import radians
context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
scene = context.scene
# emulate rotation op
R = Matrix.Rotation(radians(90), 4, 'Z') # rotate 90 about z axis
ob.matrix_world *= R

#emulate ops.anim.keyframe_insert
ks = scene.keying_sets.active
if ks:
    ks.refresh()
    for p in ks.paths:
        # check for entire array (index=-1)
        index = -1 if p.use_entire_array else p.array_index
        # insert keyframe
        ob.keyframe_insert(
                p.data_path, 
                index=index, 
                frame=30)
```

A method could be made using methods above that is passed the arguments object angle, axis and frame.

```
def rot_and_keyframe(ob, angle, axis, frame):
    ...

rot_and_keyframe(ob, radians(90), 'X', 30)
rot_and_keyframe(ob, radians(-90), 'Y', 60)
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a try. My ultimate goal is to animate the rotation of faces of a Rubik's cube and I've been having lots of trouble with x becoming z and y becoming x etc etc and what I did above is the only thing so far that didn't do that.

Comment: Never did solve the Rubik's properly. Busted it apart and put back together. Would break it down similarly as an exercise  in blender. Each move is Choose one of 3 axes to rotate to 1 of 3 other possible positions. for 1 or 2 of 3 of the "shearing plates".  which comes down to manipulating a 3 x 3 x 3 array.  Hope that makes some sense, is late.

Comment: It is not really working and my method with operators is doing the same thing. Once an axis has reached 180 degrees, further rotations go wacky. I need to be able to rotate as many times as necessary. If you are interested, [you can see my blender file](https://github.com/crowcoder/BlenderTesting). It has your script and mine saved in Text Editor. In case you could not tell, I am new to 3D modeling and 3D math.